# Getting data from GCP-Datastore for LIST

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud, gql

I want to get the bulk of data from a table of GCP-DataStore for a list of IDs.
I tried using the following query which is not supported:

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4 FROM tableName where IDs IN (:listIds)
```

Currently, I am iterating(in JAVA) for each Id and getting the data using DataStoreRepository.

How in GQL we can execute the query with IN operator, or how can we get bulk of data from datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#operators_and_comparisons) GQL does support the `IN` operator.

I suggest you to try [Custom GQL query methods](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_datastore.html#_custom_gql_query_methods). Here is an example from the documentation:

```
public interface TraderRepository extends DatastoreRepository<Trader, String> {

  @Query("SELECT * FROM traders WHERE name = @trader_name")
  List<Trader> tradersByName(@Param("trader_name") String traderName);

  @Query("SELECT * FROM  test_entities_ci WHERE id = @id_val")
  TestEntity getOneTestEntity(@Param("id_val") long id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is IDs a field on your entity, or the id that's part of the key?  If the latter, you'll want to use [findAllById](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RC2/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_datastore.html#_find_by_id_s)

Comment: ID is a column of the entity.